# A book misprinted "$\sin x\cos x$" as "$\sin\cos x$" in an equation. Can the erroneous equation still be solved by elementary or numerical methods?

Tags: trigonometry, soft-question, education

In my textbook of trigonometry there is, for an exercise, a misprint (fix typo) on this equation
$$3\sin ^2\left(x\right)-\sqrt{3}\color{red}{\sin \left(\cos \left(x\right)\right)}+3\sin \left(2x\right)-2\sqrt{3}\cos ^2\left(x\right)=0 \tag1$$
because it is missed the $x$ for the operator $\sin$. Here there is the original photo:

[image]

> I believe that with derivatives or numerical methods can be solved the $(1)$. Is there no hope of being able to find the solution in case there is a misprint like this?

Comment: Sure looks as if it's supposed to be $\sqrt{3} \sin x \cos x$.

Comment: @JohnHughes Hi, yes of course. In fact I have written that is missed the $x$ for the $\sin$ operator in the red rectangle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, equations like that (without the correction) are pretty much hopeless to solve, except that sometimes you get lucky, and say 'suppose $\cos x = 0$...', then $\sin x = \pm1$, and the $\sin \cos x$ term goes away completely, and it turns out that everything else works fine when $\sin x = +1$, say...but that's just blind luck.

You can also write out the whole mess with Taylor series and hope to get some sort of recurrence you can solve.. .but it's a long shot.

Comment: I am totally agree with your answer. Thank you very much. In fact I have thinked to use for me the Taylor series. +1 and I accept your answer...after 7 minutes :-)

Comment: Nah...wait and see whether someone else comes up with something better. You'd be surprised what people can think up!

Comment: I have thought well for your answer :-)

Comment: If only it had been $3\sin x$ instead of $3\sin 2x$ in the exercise, the $\cos x=0$ plan would actually have worked here. :-)

Comment: @JohnHughes People like you make MSE great- nearly all other people wouldn't suggest that the OP doesn't accept their answer yet. Thanks for all you do!